# Definition of multiple sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, abelian-groups

Suppose we have an abelian group $(G,+)$. What is the formal definition of multiple sums such as
$\sum_{i_1 \in A} \sum_{i_2 \in A_{i_1}} \cdots \sum_{i_n \in A_{i_{n-1}}}f(i_1,\ldots,i_n)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd have to tell us what $A$, $A_i$, and $f$ were for that... what do they have to do with $G$?

Comment: $A$ and all $A_i$ are some finite sets where the set $A_i$ depends on the index i. $f$ is an arbitrary function. $f : (i_1, ..., i_n) \rightarrow $ some element of $G$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all the sets in the subscripts are finite, you can give a recursive definition:

\[
\sum_{i \in A} f(i) = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{if }A = \emptyset \\
f(a) + \textstyle\sum_{i \in A \setminus \{a\}} f(i) &\text{if }a \in A
\end{cases}
\]

Now you can just apply the above definition repeatedly to eliminate each $\sum$ from left to right.

Two things need to be proven here: first, that any $\sum$ can be eliminated by application of these rules, and second, that the result does not depend on which $a$ is chosen in the second clause.

The first is proven by induction on the size of $A$. If $|A| = 0$ then it is empty, so the first clause applies and the $\sum$ is eliminated. If I can eliminate sums over sets of size $n$, then I can eliminate sums over sets of size $n + 1$ using the second clause. So every sum can be eliminated.

Now, clearly when $|A| = 0$ the result does not depend on which $a$ is chosen, because no $a$ is chosen, and moreover when $|A| = 1$ there is only one possible choice, so no ambiguity is introduced. Now suppose $|A| \ge 2$, so it contains two distinct elements $a \not= b$, say. It suffices to prove that $f(a) + \sum_{i \in A \setminus \{a\}} f(i) = f(b) + \sum_{i \in A \setminus \{b\}} f(i)$. \[\begin{align}
f(a) + \sum_{i \in A \setminus \{a\}} f(i)
  &= f(a) + f(b) + \sum_{i \in A \setminus \{a,b\}} f(i) \\
  &= f(b) + f(a) + \sum_{i \in A \setminus \{a,b\}} f(i) \\
  &= f(b) + \sum_{i \in A \setminus \{b\}} f(i).
\end{align}\]

Comment: And as an exercise, you can prove that the result is the same as $\sum_{(i_1,\ldots,i_n)\in A\times A_1\times\cdots A_{n-1}} f(i_1,\ldots,i_n)$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: not quite, because in fact it's not $A_1$ but $A_{i_1}$, so which set you use in the second sum depends on which element you're looking at in the first. But if that's the same set every time, then yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: @BenMillwood
"You can prove that this tells you what to do with every set by induction on the size of A"
What exactly do you mean, i.e. what property should be proved?

Comment: @BenMillwood
I defined the sum over ONE set in other way: first of all we prove that in abelian group sum doesn't depend on the order of summands and then we arbitrarily number the elements of set A: $A = \{i_1, ..., i_n \}$ and define the sum as
$\sum_{i \in A} f(i) = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{if }A = \emptyset \\
\textstyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(i_k) &\text{if } |A|=n
\end{cases}$

But i still don't understand whether there is some recursive definition for multiple sum :(

Comment: The multiple sum is just lots of single sums: your sum is $\sum_{i_1 \in A} g(i_1, \dots, i_n)$, where $g(i_1, \dots, i_n) = \sum_{i_2 \in A_{i_1}} h(\dots)$, etc.